# How to use java to get element of xml document, but in xml string format?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have read some links on parsing xml document like below:

```
<inventory>
    <book year="2000">
        <title>Snow Crash</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <isbn>0553380958</isbn>
        <price>14.95</price>
    </book>

    <book year="2005">
        <title>Burning Tower</title>
        <author>Larry Niven</author>
        <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
        <price>5.99</price>
    </book>

    <!-- more books... -->

</inventory>
```

using DOM parsing:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(<uri_as_string>);
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(<xpath_expression>);
```

however, their purpose are mostly to get **VALUE** of some node(s) by tag or by attribute from the document.

My purpose is to get the entire **XML STRING** of the node(s) back. For example, using Xpath /inventory/book[@year='2005'], i want to get the following xml back in a single string, i.e.

```
    <book year="2005">
        <title>Burning Tower</title>
        <author>Larry Niven</author>
        <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
        <price>5.99</price>
    </book>
```

What is the API used for this purpose? And do i even need the DOM parsing  in this case? Thanks,

COMMENT:

Maybe I should emphasize that I am asking this question as a XML related one, not a text file processing question. Concepts like 'tag', 'attribute', 'Xpath' still apply. The DOM model is not totally irrelevant. It's just that instead of getting the 'element' or value of a node, i want to get the whole node.

The given answers can not solve problems like: how to get a node in xml string format, given the node's Xpath representation, such as `//book` or `/inventory/book[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

DOM parsers are designed to get values from the them not for actual file content.

You can use a simple file reader instead of XML.

Read line by line using a simple `FileReader` and check the line for the Condition and if the condition is met start the read content to concat as you want until the End of the node .

You can do it as

```
if(lineReadFromFile=="Your String Condition"){
    //collect the desired file content here untill the end of the Node is found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read XML from file (consider it to be a normal text file) using **FileReader**. Simple apply the condition for example :

```
if(line.equals("<book year="2005"><title>Burning Tower</title>")) {
     // retrieve/save the required content
}
```